# How to call body onload JavaScript functions in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular

We are migrating old JavaScript projects into Angular 10.
There are many JavaScript functions calling from `body onload`. What is the best way to call such functions in Angular 10? Please help.

Comment: This is a little unclear, you should show some existing code.

Comment: call the funcions ngOnInit  and take a look of the angular lifecyle hooks in following reference https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular 10 you can call a javascript function on body load using ngOnInit() function

call the the function inside the ngOnInit() function .

**like this**

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.checkNotifiactionToken(); //this is your custom function which is you want to call on body load
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There should be a specific approach, when you are migrating old js body onload function. And you have multiple functions as well.

To keep it in mind `angular component` solution, I would suggest 1st to find which are the function required for which `components`.

let's suppose you have five `function` are in body `onload`.

One function required before even loading the app to get some configuration, move it to app initializer, you need to setup `APP_INITIALIZER` in angular.

Other two function required to load the 1st paint or home page. Move them to their respective components or you can use `route resolver`, if you have routing or `ngOninit`

The key point here to for better performance, in `Angular` we have multiple way to do it. You need to find that match where things required and fit.